# Does John 1:3 contradict Isaiah 44:24?

Tags: origin

How could all things come into being and "apart or without" Him come into being that has come into being? This question is for those groups or others that deny the deity of Jesus Christ, who say He is a created being and those that believe He did not pre-exist His incarnation.

Please reconcile John 1:3 with Isaiah 44:24? "Thus says the Lord, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you in the womb, I, the Lord am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE."

Comment: Sorry, Mr Bond, but your first paragraph is difficult to understand.  What are you trying to say?  Can you rephrase it so even people like me can follow you?  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewShanks By the #'s Genesis 1:1 and John 1:1 start out with, "in beginning." The main thought at Genesis 1:1 is, WHAT HAPPENED "in beginning." The main thought of John 1:1 is on WHO EXISTED "in beginning." John 1:1 beginning "antecedes" the Genesis 1:1 beginning. Since this is true the Apostle John under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit said, "and apart from Him/Jesus Christ nothing came into being that has come into being." This is BEFORE the Son incarnated at John 1:14. Paul backs this up at Colossians 1:16-17. At vs17, how can all things hold together by Him if He is a created being?

Comment: OK, I understand that.  But what do you mean by this: _Obviously this would also mean He could not have pre-existed His incarnation which I believe He did according to John 1:1-2._?  Thanks. (Sorry for not getting it.)

Comment: @AndrewShanks In other words, if Jesus Christ at John 1:3 where it says, "and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being" then He could not have preexisted (according to the anti's that deny His deity) before He incarnated or became flesh according to John 1:14. As I stated the "in beginning" at John 1:1 antecedes the Genesis 1:1 beginning. What the anti's don't get is the fact that Jesus Christ came as a witness of the spoken word. According to John 14:9 the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father.

Comment: @Mr.Bond _The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father._ Does this mean **(a)** That all God's manifestations (_theophanies_) in the OT are, in fact, manifestations of the Son (_christophanies_)? Or that **(b)** only with the incarnation was the Father revealed through His Son, Jesus Christ? Or **(c)** what?

Comment: @MigueldeServet As I said, the Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father, and I mean this physically. Jesus Himself stated the Father cannot be seen. John 5:37, John 6:46. The Apostle John at John 1:18. Paul at 1 Timothy 6:16 and John at 1 John 4:12. And don't forget what Jesus said at John 4:24. So my answer would be (a). Can you provide a verse that says, "God the Father" appeared? Who appeared here: Genesis 16:9-13, Genesis 18:1-33, Gen 22:11-14, (my personal favorite). Exodus 3:2-4,17, Judges 6:11-24, Judges 13:2-23, and Daniel 3:23-29. Oops, I almost forgot Genesis 17:1-2

Comment: @Mr.Bond _Who appeared here[?] (list of verses with theophanies/christophanies)_ Why can't all those occasions be manifestations of the "Lord’s angel", as is explicitly said in nearly all of them? Oh, BTW, I almost forgot to ask: what do you make of [Genesis 17:1](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Genesis%2017:1&book=genesis&chapter=17&verse=1)?

Comment: @MigueldeServet They are all appearances of the angel of the Lord. The angel of the Lord first appears to Hagar at Genesis 16:7, He says HE will multiply her descendants, vs10. He says she will have a son named Ishmael. These are the Arabs of today. At vs13 Hagar says she has seen God. At Genesis 17:1,2, The Lord appears to Abram saying, "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me and be blameless. Vs2, And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly. Question? Is the being who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiplies Abram descendants?

Comment: @Mr.Bond _At vs13 Hagar says she has seen God. (…) Is the being who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiplies Abram descendants?_ Obviously Hagar, having seen the "Lord’s angel", thought (**wrongly** …) that she had seen the Lord Himself …

Comment: @MigueldeServet How do you know she thought wrongly? Did Jacob also think wrongly at Genesis 32:30? Who appeared to Jacob a second time at Genesis 9-15, vs13, "Then God went up from him in the place where He/God had spoken with him." At Genesis 18:1 the Lord appears to Abraham and all through the chapter God has a chat with Abraham. At vs33, As soon as He/God finished speaking the Lord departed;" And back at Genesis 17:1-2, vs22, "And when He/God finished talking with him, God went up from Abraham." Your the one who is "thinking wrongly,  your ASSUMING the angel of the Lord is an actual angel.

Comment: _Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?_ No, just one last comment :)

Comment: @Mr.Bond **(MB)** _They are all appearances of the angel of the Lord._ **(MdS)** _Oh, BTW, I almost forgot to ask: what do you make of [Genesis 17:1](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Genesis%2017:1&book=genesis&chapter=17&verse=1)?_ **(MB)** _You['re] the one who is "thinking wrongly, you['re] ASSUMING the angel of the Lord is an actual angel._ I had given you the opportunity of being open and honest with [Genesis 17:1](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Genesis%2017:1&book=genesis&chapter=17&verse=1): you flunked it ...

Comment: **P.S.** Whoever appears to Abraham, says to him: “I am the sovereign God (_'el shadday_).”

Comment: Good question, needs scoping, this is not a question that is going to get one correct answer on this site.

Comment: @PeterTurner I edited the question without giving my answer. I hope it meets stack exchange requirements. And as a side note the Scriptures do not contradict themselves, which I'm sure you know. When we disagree, your view may not be correct, mine may not be, both of us could be wrong, but both cannot be right at the same time in the same place. There may be thousands of "applications of a given text, but there is ONLY ONE CORRECT MEANING.

Comment: The word of God is very sharp clearly differentiates between soul and Spirit. Jesus is here the soul and the Father is the Spirit. Put these two together and you get Jesus Christ, Son of God. Thus, it is the Father that was in the beginning. Although Jesus is after the imputation privy to the Father’s mind. Moreover, the case that there are many “beginnings” complicates the broader issue. For starters there is the beginning of the earth, the beginning of life on earth, the beginning of the world, etc. (the latter started after the flood)

Comment: @Mr.Bond This site does not exist to present truth - just Christianity. This explains why it's so confusing with unbiblical ideas like the comment above. Christianity is a smorgasbord of ideas from men and the reality of the bible - except for the bits that men have changed of course! It also explains why truth - biblical truth from scripture is usually frowned on and d-voted. While creeds and all manner of other writings have a favoured response.

Comment: If Jesus was fully God AND fully man (Heb 2:17), he would have had a soul, which he would have started out with according to 1 Cor 15:46.

Comment: @cons but he is not fully God and fully man - where did you get that from?

Comment: Well, John 1:18, Col 1:19, 2:9 imply that that is so. Question is if he was so already at birth, or if this happened later at his baptism and dove anointing.

Answer (score 0):

Your consternation appears to lie in the confusion between things created and things that are Eternal. There are two realms, the Material and The Spiritual. The material realm consists of our world and and all other things in space. The Spiritual realm consists of all things which have no beginning and no end

Comment: Welcome to the boards. I have no "feeling of anxiety or dismay/consternation. My question is simple? Since John 1:3b says, "and apart from Him/Logos/Word/Jesus Christ nothing came into being that has come into being" how could He have not preexisted His incarnation and be not God? Also, Isaiah 44:24 says, "I, the Lord am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE." So how does one "reconcile" this clear contradiction here at Isaiah to what John 1:3 says and Colossians 1:16? Would you agree that there is only one creator?

Comment: Angels are part of the spirit realm yet they are created and have a beginning.

Comment: God IS by Himself, there is no logos *person* with Him. What God *says* happens, that’s it! The logos does not create, God creates thru his logos or word as John has expressed. It’s a very simple concept, according to the text and John’s inspired update. Necessary to show what Jesus came from. Jesus isn’t just another son of God, he is the logos of God.

Answer (score -1):

**Please reconcile John 1:3 with Isaiah 44:24?**

> "...apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being.”

> "Thus says the Lord, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you in the womb, I, the Lord am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE."

It seems some have trouble reading the actual words we are given. Intent on joining the dots in a pre-determined pattern, they miss the intended and simple meaning.

There is no complication or contradiction or reconciliation needed when one reads the words without a presupposed theology.

There is no 'HE' in John 1:1-3. This is a literary device at best to simulate the logos' intimate connection with God - which is 'divine' and 'with' God. (anything *with* God is not God) There is no 'person' called the logos - this is a fabricated dogma to help support a pre-existing Jesus.

This is confirmed in 1 John 1:1-2 concerning the logos...

> **That which** was from the beginning, **which** we have heard, **which** we have seen with our own eyes, **which** we have gazed upon and touched with our own hands—this is the Word of life. 2And this is the life that was revealed; we have seen it and testified to it, and we proclaim to you the eternal life that was with the Father and was revealed to us.

So the logos is not a person, but the presence, power and life of God in His word. This understanding of the logos is expressed repeatedly though the NT. The disciples understood what Jesus came from - they could now touch and proclaim God's means of giving life - the logos - now made flesh. Now, in this new age and the age to come, Jesus is the source of new life - even raising the dead with his word. John 5:29

This word, or will or purpose of God (translated as statement, story, news and many others) was made into a man - Jesus ~4BC. ***That which***, as 1 J 1 shows, represents a most basic expression of God - His word - is now a man. Not 'fully God', but filled with the fullness of God - bearing His image, likeness and holy nature.

> For in Him all the fullness of Deity dwells in bodily form Col 2:9

Deity *dwells* in him. He is not deity, but the fullest *expression* of this one God.

> For the word (logos) of God is living and active, and sharper than any two-edged sword, penetrating even as far as the division of soul and spirit... Heb 4:12

No person here either. Just as is in no other 'logos' verse in the NT.

The Isaiah 44:24 reference indicates ONE God who created. Well, everyone knows that if they read the OT for a few minutes. Jesus confirmed this fact with his statement-

> Now this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom You have sent. John 17:3

Every NT writer confirmed this too - none broke ranks to introduce a new fancy God with 3 parts (1 Cor 8:6) And none making Jesus also God - except for a few precious 'proof-texts' that are heavily read-into, terribly altering their intended message.

John says God creates by His word. The logos isn't the maker - it's a word! Just as God's spirit is not a separate entity apart from God, God's logos is not independent either - it is what God "says".

- God says let there be light - and so it is. Did the 'says' make light? Not on its own, if God didn't say it it wouldn't be.
- John needed to explain God’s logos as that *which* Jesus came from and isn’t just another ‘son of God’. This information is critical to the whole NT plan of salvation!

The insistence on a 'person' called the logos is a futile attempt to create a necessary 'pre-existent Jesus' to fit traditional dogma - superseding the Apostolic Church Fathers inspired writings - and inventing a new gospel.

We were warned!

++++++++++++++++++

The OP originally had a Colossians reference also suggesting that Jesus made everything. This is nonsense, and again, is simply remedied by reading in context and not making stuff up.

> because in Him were created all things in the heavens and upon the earth, the visible and the invisible, whether thrones or lordships or rulers or authorities; all things have been created through Him and unto Him. Col 1:16

- IN him - not BY him.
- things IN heaven - not THE heavens.
- things ON earth - not THE earth.
- *Through* him, *for* him - not BY him

From the Gr. δι' (di') often meaning 'because of', 'by reason of'- "through" is not about the method of creating, but the **purpose** of creating.
Thus all things have their ultimate purpose in Christ. For without Christ as redeemer, there is nothing of Godly value in all His earthly creation. All things are made to have their meaning and potential in Christ - this was the plan from the beginning. Only in Christ are we in the image of God. Rom 8:29

The plainly spoken words reveal a truth which is consistently mis-read and mis-represented. The new creation, of the church centred on the coming kingdom, and its presence in Christ already, is the topic here, not a Genesis creation.

Further confirmed by the context of the continuing Colossians passage-

> ...He is the beginning, the **firstborn from the dead**, so that He Himself will come to have first place in everything. [More here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48843/what-does-it-mean-for-christ-to-be-firstborn-from-the-dead/48901?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C30.1971#48901).

So Jesus is the firstborn of the **new creation**. Being the firstborn of the Genesis creation is unscriptural and ignoring immediate context and all NT narratives.

- how can Jesus 'come to have first place in everything', if he made everything?
- being 'firstborn of the dead' is the first to change from mortal flesh to immortal flesh - having life by the spirit instead of the blood. Jesus was never immortal to begin with - scripture readily bears his out.

To be perfectly clear - Jesus did not exist before he was conceived. He was only a plan, a prophecy and a promise. The logos is not a pre-existing Jesus. Anything other than this is derived not from scripture.

Paul has joined the dots for us without equivocation - stating the plain truth and confirming the nature of Jesus quite consistently. It is this Jesus Paul speaks of, who most certainly did not make the heavens and the earth as he wasn't born yet.

Comment: Your right, "some are having trouble reading the actual words" and it ain't me. So tell me, what literary device was used here: "and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being." Note John 1:2, "That one was in the beginning with God." Explain why God's "Word or spoken words" would not be with God? It doesn't say God's word or words, it says "The Word existed, how? The Word existed with the God. The Word and The God are distinct, there is a subject/object distinction between the two. "The Word was God." So whatever God is, The Word is, and vice versa.

Comment: 1 I didn't say wasn't with God. 2 where does it say "existed"? 3 "Word was God" is NOT the only way to translate that verse. Instead of sticking to your guns - consider what the text says and not what you thought it said. Your whole Q is based on 'made up' understanding.

Comment: Vs2, "He was in the beginning with God" means He existed with God. If He did not exist with God in the beginning then how can all things "without Him" come into being? The Word existed before He was born at vs14. You still have not explained, "and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being." Reconcile those words with Isaiah 44:24, I, the Lord, am the maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF. And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE." And your sticking to your guns that John 1:1-14 is God's spoken words. Are not your spoken words already with you?

Comment: :) 1 or two translations say 'existed' this is not a required meaning. You are merely desperate to enforce personage. The word wasn't born - Jesus was born. NOW we have a person. Having a meaningful discussion is pointless if you just make stuff up! AND ignore what I actually said - and ignore or rewrite what God said.

Comment: **IN him - not BY him** - The latter half of the very same verse reads *all things have been created by/through him*.

Comment: exactly, through is not by.  God creates through His word, and now through Jesus, His human logos.

Comment: +1 An excellent presentation of a certain way of interpreting John 1. "the Word was God" IMO is one of the worst common translation decisions in the Bible (the biggest being using 'LORD' instead of 'YHWH', which leads to all sorts of confusion). It renders the sentence incomprehensible. 'the Logos was divine' or even 'the Logos was God-ish', or also something like Mr. Bond's suggestion but tweaked a bit, "What God was, the Word was" all better convey the Greek, IMHO.

Comment: You've declared the logos is not a person and offered, as a proof, that there is no "he" (a masculine personal pronoun) in John 1:1-3.  Then when "him" (a masculine personal pronoun) appears in verse 3 you say it's not a person because it refers to logos, which you have already declared to be a non-person by the absence of "he".  The fact is, however, that a masculine personal pronoun appears (twice) in John's prologue in reference to logos, so this particular line of reasoning falls apart.

Comment: @Mike yet you insist it is a 'person' with no proof whatsoever - just based on John using a 'he' in this place and no other in the entire NT. Excellent exegesis.

Comment: This insistence on the pre-incarnated λόγος being _personal_, just because it is, in Greek, a noun of **masculine gender**, and therefore it is referred to with the **masculine pronoun** οὗτος, is pretty desperate indeed …

Comment: @MigueldeServet & user47952  If He was created, how can all things "apart or without" Him come into being? The text emphatically says, "without him not one thing came into being that has come into being." If the Word/spoken word came into being, then according to John 1:3, the Word came into being through the Word. That's a contradiction; therefore, the Word could not have come into being. QED. This is a simplistic syllogism. There is no logical/rational way around this conclusion. Show me your exegesis of the passage in a way that demonstrates how you can deny the obvious of what it says?

Comment: The logos is God’s word, not a person who has a beginning. You and your theology are the contradiction here. That’s what the 1J1 reference shows plainly- no person, just the word, will and power of God **which** was made into a person, Jesus.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Read this together with my comment of about 11 hours ago. The λόγος is indeed eternal, and πάντα δι’αὐτοῦ ἐγένετο. But the λόγος is **not** a person. It ( it …) got incarnated (σὰρξ ἐγένετο) in the **person** of Jesus of Nazareth, the Son of God, the Messiah. This is simple, without being simplistic …

Comment: @MigueldeServet I just found the following regarding John 1:1-3 on Stack Exchange. It initially deals with John 1:1 and the JW understanding. However, answers 2 and 3 (especially 3 for our purposes) go into great detail regarding the Greek. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/in-john-11c-should-the-greek-word-%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BD%B8%CF%82-be-translated-into-english-as-a-god-o The bottom line has to do with John 1:3b, "and apart from HIM nothing came into being that has not come into being." I would love to hear your refutation and btw, an "it" did not incarnate, God incarnated.

Comment: There is no incarnation. God becoming a man is without scripture. All God did was ‘call’ His son into existence thru Mary by His Spirt. A man and nothing more, except holy and without sin. Perhaps a simple, plainly expressed Q will narrow down the problem you seem to need solved.

Comment: @Mr.Bond To refer to God’s λόγος, **before** the incarnation in the person of Jesus of Nazareth with “he” is, once again, misleading, nay wrong, because the **only** reason why the λόγος is referred to, in the original Greek, with a masculine pronoun, is that λόγος **happens** to be a noun of masculine gender. Just like σοφία, “wisdom”, **happens** to be a feminine noun, and πνεῦμα, “spirit”, **happens** to be a neuter noun.

Comment: @user47952 It is not enough to simply say that “God called His son into existence thru Mary by His Spirt“. You surprisingly omit to mention His Word, of which (which …) the Gospel of John says, ὁ λόγος σὰρξ ἐγένετο, appropriately translated “the Word became flesh“. The virgin conception is the miraculous side of the mysterious event, the incarnation of God’s Word.

Comment: @MigueldeServet yes, correct. My veiled reference to ‘called’ was my way of saying the same.

Comment: @user47952 Why a "veiled reference"? Why not speak as clearly and forcefully of "His Word" (_logos_) as of "His Spirit"?

Answer (score -1):

The KJV renders John 1:1-3 as:

> 1 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the
> Word was God. 2 The same was in the beginning with God. 3 All things
> were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was
> made. 4 In him was life; and the life was the light of men.

From the point of view that Jesus is a created being, this rendering of the scripture supports that nothing was made without "the Word" Jesus. This is inline with the ideas in Colossians 1:15-17 (KJV):

> 15 Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every
> creature: 16 For by him were all things created, that are in heaven,
> and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones,
> or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by
> him, and for him: 17 And he is before all things, and by him all
> things consist.

From the point of view that Jesus is a created being these verses support eachother and support (at least not contradict) the following ideas

1. Jesus is a separate being from God (“with God”  & “image of the
   invisible God”).
2. Jesus was the first creation by which all other
   things were made (“In the beginning”… (God almighty did not have a
   beginning) & “firstborn of every creature” (Col 1:15).

Maybe more important: it is interesting to notice that the earliest available Greek manuscripts of the John 1:3,4 there is  no punctuation between the verses 3 and 4. This causes different possible renderings & translations. A common class of renderings is that similar as in the KJV. But for example [Nestle and Aland](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/10001/19999/ch/004cdf738f7bed02b14c891d2c9d2608/) place the punctuation different and there the last part of verse 3, is the start of the sentence of verse 4. This would lead to different meaning and translation obviously. Due to this uncertainty in the data from the oldest manuscripts there is little justification about being very dogmatic about any particular translation, interpretation and conclusions derived from these verses of John 1:3,4.